# Ajax request don't send data to controller metod

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

i am new to laravel 8 and ajax and also i am working in a group.
I have a blade view to view the data of a user and since from this view I would like to make it possible to modify some data without a form tag I have made a js script to send the new data to be modified to a method of a controller but this data does not never arrive at the controller as I notice that the mysql db  and the profilo view  is not updated, however some "debug" printouts report a success.

Where am I wrong? Thanks in advance.

This is the controller

```
class ProfiloUtente extends Controller{

    public function visualizzaProfiloUtente(Request $request)
    {
        $id_utente = $request->session()->get('LoggedUser');
        $flag_attore = $request->session()->get('Attore');
        $utente = null;

        if ($flag_attore === Attore::CITTADINO_PRIVATO) {
            $utente = CittadinoPrivato::getById($id_utente);
        }
        if ($flag_attore === Attore::DATORE_LAVORO) {
            $utente = DatoreLavoro::getById($id_utente);
        }
        if ($flag_attore === Attore::MEDICO_MEDICINA_GENERALE) {
            $utente = MedicoMG::getById($id_utente);
        }

        return view('profilo', compact('utente'));
    }

    public function modificaProfiloUtente(Request $request)
    {
        $id_utente = $request->session()->get('LoggedUser');
        $flag_attore = $request->session()->get('Attore');
        $this->validation($request);
        $input = $this->generalInput($request);

        try {
            User::updateInfo($id_utente, $input['nuovo_codice_fiscale'], $input['nome'], $input['cognome'], $input['citta_residenza'],
                $input['provincia_residenza'], $input['email'], $input['password']);

            if ($flag_attore === Attore::CITTADINO_PRIVATO) {
                CittadinoPrivato::updateCittadino($input['codice_fiscale_attuale'], $input['nuovo_codice_fiscale']);
            }
            elseif ($flag_attore === Attore::DATORE_LAVORO) {
                $input['partita_iva'] = $request->input('iva');
                $input['nome_azienda'] = $request->input('nome_azienda');
                $input['citta_azienda'] = $request->input('citta_sede_aziendale');
                $input['provincia_azienda'] = $request->input('provincia_sede_aziendale');
                DatoreLavoro::updateDatore($input['codice_fiscale_attuale'], $input['nuovo_codice_fiscale'], $input['partita_iva'], $input['nome_azienda'], $input['citta_azienda'], $input['provincia_azienda']);
            }
            elseif ($flag_attore === Attore::MEDICO_MEDICINA_GENERALE) {
                $input['partita_iva'] = $request->input('iva');
                MedicoMG::updateMedico($input['codice_fiscale_attuale'], $input['nuovo_codice_fiscale'], $input['partita_iva']);
            }
        }
        catch(QueryException $ex){
            return back()->with('update-error', 'Errore, modifica non avvenuta.');
        }

        return redirect('/profilo');
    }
    
    /**
     * Raggruppa le validazioni dei dati comuni
     * @param Request $request
     */
    private function validation(Request $request) {
        $validation = $request->validate([
            'cf' => 'required|min:16|max:16',
            'nome' => 'required|max:30',
            'cognome' => 'required|max:30',
            'citta_residenza' => 'required|max:50',
            'provincia_residenza' => 'required|max:50',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'psw' => 'required|min:8|max:40'
        ]);
    }

    private function generalInput(Request $request)
    {
        $input = [];
        $input['nuovo_codice_fiscale'] = $request->input('cf');
        $input['codice_fiscale_attuale'] = $request->input('cf_attuale');
        $input['nome'] = $request->input('nome');
        $input['cognome'] = $request->input('cognome');
        $input['citta_residenza'] = $request->input('citta_residenza');
        $input['provincia_residenza'] = $request->input('provincia_residenza');
        $input['email'] = $request->input('email');
        $input['password'] = $request->input('psw');
        return $input;
    }
}
```

This is the route

```
Route::post('/modificaProfilo', [ProfiloUtente::class, 'modificaProfiloUtente'])->name('modifica.profilo');
```

This the script for ajax request in blade view

```
var data = '<?php echo json_encode($utente) ?>';
data = JSON.parse(data);

getDataProfilePage(data); //get values ​​to update 

sendDataProfilePage(data,"{{route('modifica.profilo') }}","{{csrf_token()}}");
```

sendDataProfilePage function in public/script/script.js

```
function sendDataProfilePage(data, url, csrfToken) {

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("_token", csrfToken);

    for (key in data) {

        if (key == "codice_fiscale") {

            formData.append("cf", data[key]);
            formData.append("cf_attuale", data[key]);

        } else if (key == "password") {

            formData.append("psw", data[key]);

        } else if (key == "partita_iva") {

            formData.append("iva", data[key]);

        } else {

            formData.append(key, data[key])
        }

    }

    for (var pair of formData.entries()) { //print for feedback
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }



    //send data
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url);

    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", csrfToken);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {

        console.log("ready state " + request.readyState); //print for feedback
        console.log("status  " + request.status); //print for feedback

        if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

            if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) { //detect request succes

                console.log("responseStatus  " + request.status + " " + request.statusText); //print for feedback

            } else {
                console.log("responseStatus  " + request.status + " " + request.statusText); //print for feedback
            }
        }
    };

    request.send(formData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A FormData object is sent with content-type multipart/form-data not application/x-www-form-urlencoded. In your code remove the line where you set the content-type header, the correct content-type header will be set automatically.

Comment: I tried to delete the line to set content-type and I also tried to set content-type as multipart / form-data but it still doesn't work

Comment: In reality, eliminating the explicit header of the content-types worked but I did not realize it since I discovered that there is a further problem, the validation of the data on the backand side returns the profile page from which the request starts, effectively stopping the execution of the method.